# Is the number of stamens always 9 for geranium?

Tags: botany, reproduction, structural-biology, flowers

We are studing in class the reproduction of plants.
We start the lesson by observing some components of flowers, it was the **Géranium**.

First of all we start counting the number of **sepals** , **petals** and **stamens**.
The problem is that I found:

5 sepals

5 petals

9 stamens

and every other student found that the number of stamens was 9 or 8 or 10.

I asked my teacher and he says that he counted the number of stamens many times and he found 9.

Is it really 9? Do the number of stamens is depending of the number of sepals or petals? Is there any relation ?

Comment: Are you positive it was a geranium? From what I've seen, geraniums usually have 5 stamens. Marsh St. Johnswort, on the other hand, is a flower that has 9 stamens (http://www.ct-botanical-society.org/galleries/pics_t/triadenumvirg_fl.jpg). In any case, more details would be nice. Were you looking at actual specimens? Where did they come from? Did you collect them from the wild or from a greenhouse? If they came from the wild, then it would be important to know what your location is.

Comment: Yes it is the geranium I taked it from school garden , I don't know if it is really 9 stamens , but I heared that stamens have to be a multiple of sepals and petals for exemple if a flower has 3 petals so stamens can be 6 or 9 and if a flower has 5 so stamens are 5 or 10 ... But there is a contradiction with the picture because this flower has 9 stamens but 5 petals ... Is there any other reference about the flower in the picture ?Do really the stamens have to be a multiple of petals ?

Comment: The stamens are not always a multiple of the petals, but they usually are. I can write up a more detailed answer in a bit. What country/climate is your school in? It might be useful to know

Comment: My school is Nador in Morocco north of africa :)

Comment: Its medditeraneen climate